# R: apply a function with arguments to a vector

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I have a data frame

```
df
#   A     B      C
#   1     2   1999
#   2     NA    1999
#   3     4    1999
#   3     3    1999
```

and a function

```
fun<- function(reason, bitmap){
  if(is.na(bitmap)){
    return(FALSE)
  }
  if(reason == bitmap){
    return(TRUE)
  }
  n<-0
  while(bitmap>=0){
    if(bitmap<2^n){
      if(reason == 2^(n-1)){
        return(TRUE)
        break}
      bitmap <- bitmap - 2^(n-1)
      n <-0
    }
    n <- n+1 
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

When I execute the function

```
fun(2,df$B)
```

I get the error message:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I understand that I need to apply function to each row of the vektor but I do not understand how to do it. I looked at apply but couldnt figure out how to solve this issue

Comment: You can do `sapply(df$B, fun, reason = 2)`

Comment: With `if(reason == bitmap)` you are comparing a scalar to a vector so returns a test result for each vector value.  If you want to check if any value of `bitmap` equals `reason` then use `if (any(reason == bitmap)` as your test.  That will return a single logical value.

Comment: @SteveM there are many reasons the function is not vectorized. `if(is.na(bitmap))` isn't vectorized, `if(reason == bitmap)` as you point out, but most importantly the `while` loop which may require different number of iterations for each item of `bitmap`. Switching to `if (any(reason == bitmap)` won't do anything overall.